# Resin.io connection error

Tags: networking

My Raspberry Pi is loaded up with the OS from Resin.io.

The latest push seems to have messed things up, now it wont download latest updates and when i try to open the terminal session or purge data i get "tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up". However it says it's online and i am able to ping it.

Any ideas? I've looked through their Docs and am getting nothing...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Kostas from [resin.io](https://resin.io).

Your issue is probably linked to SD card corruption resulting from power issues. We have seen this problem before and [it is fairly common](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=36533).

I would suggest switching to a robust power supply and re-flashing the SD card with the resin image.

Cheers!

Comment: Now this is what you call customer support going above and beyond their site's own helpdesk. +1